# Driving a 5V LED on computer chassis with 3.3V

Tags: led, 5v, 3.3v

My add-in card uses a pair of pins to drive an external activity LED, with anode "provid[ing] 220 ohm pull-up to +3.3 V".
However, the LED that I wish to drive with these pins, is designed to be driven by "LED pull-up to +5 V".
How do I proceed?

Comment: Does this LED you are trying to use have a built-in resistor?  A link to its datasheet would be helpful.

Comment: *How do I proceed* - get an appropriate LED

Comment: Eugene: no can do. The LED in question is molded.

Comment: evildemonic: I, too, wish I knew more about the part. But it is barely accessible and has no visible markings on it. I can only assume it is indeed a 5V part since that would fit the Intel ATX spec for ATX chassis LEDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they're saying is the '5V LED' has internal resistor. Your card also has a resistor (220 ohms). So what will happen is that the LED will be very dim since it will be running on 3.3V -> 220 ohm -> LED dropping resistor in series.

If you can modify the LED to short out the resistor it could work, or replace it with a plain (non-resistor) LED.